# Wondering about Java object-json serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, code-generation

I am wondering, when I google 'java object to json' I generally get the basic libraries/frameworks like Jackson and Gson. All of them serialize objects based on annotations or other concepts using reflection.

Now in some other programming languages I see significant performance gains by using generated serializing methods/functions as opposed to reflection-based serializers. An example of this is this messagepack library (https://github.com/tinylib/msgp).

My question is, can performance gains be won by doing something similar in Java for JSON-serialization? So i.e. generate serialization methods based upon given pojo's pre-compilation; and then using those during runtime.

I don't necessarily have a use-case, simply thinking speed.

Comment: For most applications on which I have worked as an engineer, the speed of parsing and generating JSON has never been a bottleneck.  Maybe you could add the use case where you see JSON being an issue?

Comment: I don't believe I need a use-case to wonder about performance gains. But let's just say a WEB API where every gained ms is nice to have. Leaving corporate software factors out of scope; like quick to market etc.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson has a module named [Afterburner](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/afterburner) which achieves significant performance boosts by creating custom serializer / deserializer classes on the fly at runtime.